# How do I get a smooth interpolation between keyframes?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am trying to make an animation system for my three.js project. I have a json file for the information. I was able to make the animation play. But, at the moment they need to be somewhere, they move to that location, instead of slowly moving to that location over time. The json file tells the program where the specific object needs to be at a certain location. For example:

Json File:

```json
{
"right": {
    "position": {
        "0.0": [0, 0, 0],
        "0.25": [0, 1, 0],
        "0.5": [1, 1, 0]
    }
}
```

Json files tells you position, at what second, then the positions.

Code:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(json.position.right)) 
  if(seconds === json.position.right[key]) {
    obj.position.x = json.right.position[key][0];
    obj.position.y = json.right.position[key][1];
    obj.position.z = json.right.position[key][2];
  }
}
```

In the code, I loop through the json file's right cube position (which  tells when the position changes happen). If the seconds match, it moves to that position.

How would I be able to get the movement inbetween the keyframes for the object?

Here is the example: https://mixed-polyester-a.glitch.me/

Here is all the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mixed-polyester-a

I used [Blockbench](https://www.blockbench.net/) to export models as .OBJ files, materials as .MTL files, and animations as .JSON files.

Sorry if it sounds confusing, didn't really know how to explain it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use an animation library such as [GSAP](https://greensock.com/)

Comment: @2pha I'll check it out. Though it would be much easier for me to be able to use a formula that would tell me how much I need to move the object a frame. If you could tell me how I could do this, that would be highly appreciated. Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three.js has [a method called MathUtils.lerp()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/MathUtils.lerp) that takes in a starting position, an ending position, and an interpolation value between `[0, 1]`. You could use this to tween your object's current position to its target destination on each frame, as demonstrated in the example below:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const ball = document.getElementById("ball");

// Set current positions
let ballPosX = 0;
let ballPosY = 0;

// Set target positions
let ballTargetX = 0;
let ballTargetY = 0;

// Update target positions on click
function onClick(event) {
  ballTargetX = event.layerX;
  ballTargetY = event.layerY;
  //console.log(event);
}

function update() {
  // Interpolate current position towards targets
  ballPosX = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(ballPosX, ballTargetX, 0.1);
  ballPosY = THREE.MathUtils.lerp(ballPosY, ballTargetY, 0.1);
  
  // Apply current position to our object
  ball.style.left = ballPosX + "px";
  ball.style.top = ballPosY + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

container.addEventListener("click", onClick);
update();
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#ball {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f90;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

#### Update:

To create a linear timeline with keyframes, I've used `gsap.to()` with the keyframes parameter to feed all the positions to the timeline. [See here and look up "keyframes"](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.to()) for more details. You can see it in action in the code demo below, you'll need to iterate through your JSON to feed that data to GSAP on your own, though. Good luck!

```js
// Set position vector
const ballPos = {x: 0, y: 0};
const positions = {
    "0.0": [0, 0],
    "0.25": [0, 100],
    "0.5": [100, 100],
    "0.75": [100, 0],
    "1.0": [0, 0],
}
const timeline = gsap.to(ballPos, {keyframes: [
  {x: positions["0.0"][0], y: positions["0.0"][1], duration: 0.0},
  {x: positions["0.25"][0], y: positions["0.25"][1], duration: 0.25},
  {x: positions["0.5"][0], y: positions["0.5"][1], duration: 0.25},
  {x: positions["0.75"][0], y: positions["0.75"][1], duration: 0.25},
  {x: positions["1.0"][0], y: positions["1.0"][1], duration: 0.25},
]});

const container = document.getElementById("container");
const ball = document.getElementById("ball");


let timelineTime = 0;
function update() {
  timelineTime += 0.001;
  timelineTime %= 1;
  timeline.seek(timelineTime);

  // Apply current position to our object
  ball.style.left = ballPos.x + "px";
  ball.style.top = ballPos.y + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#ball {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f90;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just one question: how would I know the interpolation number between frames?

Comment: Also noticed that the ball slows down as it nears it's destination. How can I get a linear movement where it moves at the same speed the whole time till it reaches the destination? @Marquizzo

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I’ll expand the answer later today.

Comment: @ARMN88 See my updated answer, I added a second demo to show a timeline with keyframes using GSAP.

Comment: Just tried this, for some reason the cube shakes when it moves. https://mixed-polyester-a.glitch.me/

Comment: Lmao I just put it underneath some code and it works now. Thanks for your help! You really helped me improve my project! Have a nice day (or night)!